# Play 2.3: Is there a point to creating an abstract controller to manage forms?

Tags: playframework, controller, playframework-2.0, abstract, modularity

I am creating an application based on Play Framework 2.3 and I want to split it into modules. When a form is submitted, the action called does pretty much always the same thing, which is like:

```
public final Result submit() {
    Result result = null;

    Form<Something> boundForm = form.bindFromRequest();
    if (boundForm.hasErrors()) {
        potentiallyDoSomething();
        result = badRequest(sometemplate.render(boundForm));
    } else {
        potentiallyDoSomethingWith(boundForm.get());
        result = redirect(route.Application.somewhere());
    }

    return result;
}
```

So, I was wondering if it would be wise to extract this generic behaviour in an abstract controller. I came up with something that I found rather [questionable](https://gist.github.com/thomaslhostis/8936b59f76c28bf84955).

Maybe I am completly out of it.

Any suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you could of course do that. You could have something like that:

```
public abstract class BaseController<T> extends Controller {

    abstract Html onFail(Form<T> form);

    abstract Call onSuccess(T elem);

    public Result submit(Class<T> clazz){

        Form<T> boundForm = form(clazz).bindFromRequest();
        if (boundForm.hasErrors()) {
            return badRequest(onFail(boundForm));
        } else {
            return redirect(onSuccess(boundForm.get()));
        }

    }

}
```

And then a controller which extends `BaseController<T>`, where T is going to be your model class (the one which you want to bind from your form). for example:

```
public class ExampleController extends BaseController<FormModel> {


    @Override
    Html onFail(Form<FormModel> form) {
        Logger.info(Json.stringify(form.errorsAsJson()));
        return someTemplate.render(form);
    }

    @Override
    Call onSuccess(FormModel elem) {
        elem.save();
        return redirect(routes.Application.index());
    }

    public Result aa(){
        return submit(FormModel.class);

    }

}
```

However, you may have in many situations one controller which is handling different model types. If you use this approach, you will need to create controller for every model. Perhaps you end up having a lot of controllers.

Comment: The typical use of this behaviour would be in a CRUD Controller, so I won't mind having one controller per model in that case. I am just wondering if it's worth it.

Comment: One other thing, I assume that you would be using a dynamic call in route definitions, for the `aa()` method. Something like : `POST    /aa    @controller.ExampleController.aa()`?

Comment: Sure. That code should be added to the `routes`. 

It may be worthy for a CRUD controller and for an app with many crud operations.